# Angular - Amplify - Passing cognito user object to another component

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm new to Cognito and stuck in a situation for some time.

I am trying to login a user using Cognito. For the very first time, the response returns challenge of NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED.

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';

...

Auth.signIn(this.username, this.password)
            .then((user: any) => {
                if (user) {
                    if (user.challengeName && user.challengeName == 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
                        this.sessionService.setUser(user);
                        this.router.navigate([this.confirmAccountUrl]);
                    } else {
                        this.router.navigate([this.dashboardUrl]);
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case 'UserNotConfirmedException':
                        this.router.navigate([this.confirmAccountUrl]);
                        break;
                    case 'NotAuthorizedException':
                        this.message = 'Your temporary password is expired and must be reset by admin';
                        break;
                    case 'UsernameExistsException':
                        this.message = 'Invalid username or password';
                        break;
                }
            });
```

I want to the user to go to the next component and provide the password there.

The problem is the **result** returned is of type **CognitoUser**. This need to be passed to the **reset-password** component.

I tried saving **result** to session and retrieve in the **reset-password** component.

```
    constructor(
    private sessionService: SessionService
) {
    this.user = this.sessionService.getUser();
}

resetPassword() {
    Auth.completeNewPassword(this.user, this.new_password)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error('Error', err));
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error TypeError: user.completeNewPasswordChallenge is not a function
```

I did some research on google and found out that **user** is actually a json object but not of type **CognitoUser**

There is no function that can parse **user** to **CognitoUser** and nor there is a function in Amplify that stores it.

Here is the session service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SessionService {

constructor(
    private sessionStorageService: SessionStorageService
) { }

setUser(user: any) {
    this.sessionStorageService.set('user', user);
}

getUser(): any {
    return this.sessionStorageService.get('user');
}
}
```

**Auth.authenticatedUser** will not return value as the user is not yet authenticated.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, and tried to reconstruct the `CognitoUser` object manually:

```
const pool = new CognitoUserPool({
      UserPoolId: cognitoObject.pool.userPoolId,
      ClientId: cognitoObject.pool.clientId,
      endpoint: cognitoObject.client.endpoint,
      Storage: window.localStorage,
      AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: cognitoObject.advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag,
})
const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
      Username: cognitoObject.username,
      Pool: pool,
      Storage: window.localStorage,
})

cognitoUser.Session = cognitoObject.Session

await Auth.completeNewPassword(cognitoUser, newPassword, cognitoObject.challengeParams)
```

Source:https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1715#issuecomment-800999983

But I couldn't get it to work, as it said `CognitoUserPool is undefined`

I fixed it with the following import statement:

`import { CognitoUser, CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';`

Comment: above code throws error `Property 'Session' does not exist on type 'CognitoUser'`